# Convert AS2 por AS3...please

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

```
   oranja.onPress = function(){
       this.startDrag(true);
}
oranja.onRelease = function(){
       this.stopDrag();
       if(this.hitTest(this._parent.trash)){
             trace("trash");
             this.unloadMovie();
       } else {
             trace("no trash");
       }
}
```

---

Comment: Do you actually expect someone to do this for you? Why don't you post details of the problem, so someone can help you learn from this.

Comment: @mdm English may not be the native language here.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 I appreciate that, I'm not asking for an English explanation, just that people don't post code and *expect* others to do things for then without so much courtesy as to describe what the problem might be or how they have already tried to solve it - whatever spoken language it may be in

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an AS3 version of this? Something like this should work:

```
oranja.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this._onPress );
oranja.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this._onRelease );

// called when we mouse down on the oranja clip
private function _onPress( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    oranja.startDrag( true )
}

// called when we mouse up on the oranja clip
private function _onRelease( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    oranja.stopDrag();
    if( oranja.hitTest( oranja.parent.trash ) )
    {
        trace( "trash" );

        // remove the event listeners
        oranja.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this._onPress );
        oranja.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this._onRelease );

        // remove the oranja clip
        oranja.parent.removeChild( oranja );
        oranja = null;
    }
    else
        trace( "not trash" );
}
```

You should probably replace the `oranja` calls in `_onPress()` and `_onRelease()` with `e.target` or `e.currentTarget`

Comment: Prefer `oranja.parent.getChildByName("trash")` to `oranja.parent.trash`